# Can "blasfêmia", "heresia" and "sacrilégio" sometimes be interchangeable?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

According to Aurélio, second edition, re. religious contexts:

> - **blasfêmia** - "palavras que ultrajam a divindade ou religião"
> - **heresia** - "ato ou palavra ofensiva à religião"
> - **sacrilégio** - "ato de profanação, uso profano de lugar ou objeto sagrado, ultraje feito a pessoa sagrada ou venerável."

In the following sentences I feel more than one word would be acceptable, but I may be wrong.  Am I?

- "Ele chutou a imagem da Santa? Mas isso é um/uma ___________
- "Eu não acredito que Cristo seja filho de Deus."  "Não diga isso, o que você acabou de dizer é um/uma _______________
- "Suspeita-se que uma de nossas freiras tenha sido engravidada pelo Padre Henrique. Se comprovado, trata-se de um/uma ____________
- "Você está sugerindo fazer amor atrás do altar? Eu jamais faria isso, sou católica e sei que seria um/uma___________

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ENGLISH** (in Portuguese below)

These three words have distinct primary meanings, and secondary meanings wich share fuzzy borders. In some contexts more than word may be interchangeably used in its secondary meaning, but the question examples fit so neatly in the primary meaning of **heresia** (second example) and **sacrilégio** (the other examples, with the possible exception of the first) that there is no doubt as to which word is more appropriate for each case.

The primary meaning of [heresia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/heresia) (see also the [article in Enciclopédia Católica Popular](http://www.portal.ecclesia.pt/catolicopedia/artigo.asp?id_entrada=901)) is:

> Doutrina contrária ao que a Igreja define como dogma ou verdade de fé.

What Centaurus has given us, to tease us, no doubt, is a secondary, loose, popular meaning of **heresia**, which is basically the same as **blasfémia.** In fact the second meaning of [*heresia* listed in Aurélio Online](http://dicionariodoaurelio.com/heresia) is simply *blasfémia.* Now, stating "eu não acredito que Jesus seja filho de Deus" is clearly contrary to Catholic and virtually every Christian church doctrines, and it will be a **heresia** to say so **if** you claim to belong to one such Faith. It is **heresia** to defend the 'wrong' version of the faith. If you do not claim to be of a faith nothing you say about it is **heresia**.

The third and fouth cases are examples of [sacrilégio](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/sacril%C3%A9gio) (see also [article in Enciclopédia Católica Popular](http://www.portal.ecclesia.pt/catolicopedia/artigo.asp?id_entrada=1732)) or "profanação de coisa sagrada." Note that priests and nuns are consecrated to God, and the breaking of their vow of chastity is a **sacrilégio pessoal.** Improper deeds in a church is **sacrilégio material**.

The first examble is the most dubious to me, for I'm not sure whether the image of a saint is sacred. If it is, kicking it is a **sacrilégio** in the strict sense; if not, it will be so in the looser sense of "violação de uma coisa que merece grande respeito" if not a "ultrage feito a pessoa sagrada ou venerável." All this is valid for catholics. For most protestants, kicking the image is, of course, the right and proper thing to do.

[Blasfémia](http://dicionariodoaurelio.com/blasfemia) was left out. An example could be this passage in [Richard Dawkins’ *The God Delusion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_God_Delusion): “The God of the Old Testament is arguably the most unpleasant character in all fiction…” which goes on with accusations of sadomasochism, megalomania, infanticide, and such like. [You can hear Dawkins himself reading the whole passage here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UA3OqrNnezc). Another example is [José Saramago’s *The Gospel According to Jesus Christ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gospel_According_to_Jesus_Christ), where the fictional Jesus does improper deeds from the point of view of most Christian faiths.

**PORTUGUÊS**

Estas três palavras têm significados primários bem distintos, e significados secundários com fronteiras mais difusas. Nalguns contextos, alguns deles poderão ser usados indistintamente nos seus sentidos secundários. Mas os exemplos da pergunta encaixam tão bem nos significados primários de **heresia** (o segundo exemplo) e de **sacrilégio** (os restantes, com a possível exceção do primeiro) que não há dúvida sobre qual das palavras usar em cada caso.

O significado primário de [heresia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/heresia) (ver também o [artigo da Enciclopédia Católica Popular](http://www.portal.ecclesia.pt/catolicopedia/artigo.asp?id_entrada=901)) é:

> Doutrina contrária ao que a Igreja define como dogma ou verdade de fé.

O que o Centaurus nos apresentou, sem dúvida para nos provocar, foi o significado secundário de **heresia**, que é basicamente **blasfémia.** Com efeito, o segundo significado de [*heresia* apresentado no Aurélio Online](http://dicionariodoaurelio.com/heresia) é simplesmente *blasfémia.* Ora, afirmar "eu não acredito que Jesus seja filho de Deus" é claramente contrário às doutrinas da Igreja Católica e da generalidade das igrejas Cristãs, e portanto será uma **heresia** afirmá-lo **e** ao mesmo tempo afirmar-se Cristão. **Heresia** é afirmar um versão ‘errada’ da fé. Se uma pessoa não afirma pertencer a uma fé, nada do que ela diga acerca dessa fé constitui heresia.

Os terceiros e quarto casos são exemplos de [sacrilégio](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/sacril%C3%A9gio) (ver também [artigo na Enciclopédia Católica Popular](http://www.portal.ecclesia.pt/catolicopedia/artigo.asp?id_entrada=1732)) ou "profanação de coisa sagrada." Padres e freiras são consagrados a Deus, e violar o seu voto de castidade é um **sacrilégio pessoal.** Fazer coisas impróprias numa igreja é um **sacrilégio material.**

O primeiro exemplo é o mais duvidoso para mim, pois não sei ao certo se uma imagem duma santa é sagrada. Se o for, chutá-la é um **sacrilégio** no sentido estrito; caso contrário, será um **sacrilégio** no sentido mais lato de "violação de uma coisa que merece grande respeito," se não mesmo "ultraje feito a pessoa sagrada ou venerável." Isto é válido para católicos. Para a maioria dos protestantes, chutar a imagem é, naturalmente, a ação correta.

Ficou de fora a [blasfémia](http://dicionariodoaurelio.com/blasfemia). Um exemplo de blasfémia poderá ser esta passagem do livro [*Deus, um Delírio* (Brasil)/*A Desilusão de Deus* (Portugal) de Richard Dawkins](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_God_Delusion): “O Deus do Antigo Testamento é talvez a personagem mais desagradável de toda a ficção…” (tradução minha) que continua com acusações de sadomasoquismo, megalomania, infanticídio e coisas assim. Podem ouvir [aqui a passagem completa lida pelo próprio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UA3OqrNnezc), em inglês naturalmente. Outro exemplo é o livro [*O Evangelho Segundo Jesus Cristo*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Evangelho_segundo_Jesus_Cristo) do José Saramago, onde Jesus faz coisas impróprias do ponto de vista da maioria das igrejas cristãs.

Comment: Cum Laude, Jacinto.  Great explanation.  I always had some doubts about  the differences between "heresia" and "blasfêmia".  Not so much about "sacrilégio".  Would you agree that "sacrilégio" refers more to an action whereas "blasfêmia" refers to ideas, words, and thoughts?  "Heresia" seems to be either one to me.

Comment: @Centaurus Yes, I'd say "blasfémia" expresses itself by means of words or thoughs, and I would add images (uncomplimentary cartoons); and sacrilégio will typically be an act. But this distinction is more about form; the substance of the matter is that "sacrilégio" is the misuse of a sacred thing, say a church, a cemetery, sacramental wine, or your own body, whereas "blasfémia" is an insult, in the strict sense, directed at God or holy figures. Heresy is the affimation of a "false" doctrine. Prostestans were viewed as heretics by catholics for a long time.